# How can I display a price in Google search results?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results

How can I display a price in Google search results like in the following screenshot?

[image: Screenshot of Google results with Price]

Answer (score 2):

You can set a price range using this parameter:

```json
  "priceRange" : "$100 - $200",
```

Example:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "LocalBusiness",
  "@id" : "WEBSITE URL",
  "name" : "BUSINESS NAME",
  "logo" : "LOGO URL",
  "telephone" : "PHONE NUMBER",
  "email" : "EMAIL ADDRESS",
  "sameAs" : [ "URL #1", "URL #2" ],
  "url" : "WEBSITE URL",
  "image" : "IMAGE URL",
  "priceRange" : "$000 - $000",
  "description" : "BUSINESS DESCRIPTION",
  "address" : {
    "@type" : "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress" : "STREET ADDRESS",
    "addressLocality" : "CITY",
    "addressRegion" : "STATE ABBREVIATION",
    "postalCode" : "ZIP CODE"
  },
  "geo" : {
    "@type" : "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude" : "LATITUDE COORDINATES",
    "longitude" : "LONGITUDE COORDINATES"
  }
        }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Try it out with Structured Data testing tool:
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

---

Link to official scheme priceRange: http://schema.org/priceRange

---

Link to schema price: http://schema.org/price

Answer (score 0):

Markup your product/service with the [schema guidelines](http://schema.org/price). Google may pick up your data and display the price point as it does in your example.

Keep in mind, this does not guarantee that it will display.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is part of Google snippet. You can make some good condition for snippet but you can not influence from 100%.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.   Can you expand this?   Can you link to documentation from Google about the snippet?